# Serializing jqGrid's edit data to JSON

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

After a user edits data in jqGrid, I would like to return a formatted JSON string back to the server to be consumed. 
Below is a sample of what the server expects to receive:

```
{
  "aptitudeArrayList":[
    {
      "skill":"VITS",
      "value":2,
      "id":2,
      "color":"RED"
    },
    {
      "skill":"GBFM",
      "value":6,
      "id":1,
      "color":"GREEN"
    },
    {
      "skill":"JSON",
      "value":4,
      "id":3,
      "color":"RED"
    },
    {
      "skill":"CASTLEROCK",
      "value":7,
      "id":4,
      "color":"RED"
    }
  ],
  "cell":12412,
  "line":"FIRST_LINE",
  "name":"Barop",
  "id":1,
  "region":"The end",
  "available":true
}
```

Here is a segment of my ColModel:

```
...
{
    name:'cell',
    label:'Cell #',
    width:80,
    align:'center',
    editable:true,
    editrules:{required:true, integer:true},
    editoptions:{size:10, maxlength:10}
},
{
    name:'available',
    label:'Available',
    formatter:'checkbox',
    width:46,
    align:'center',
    editable:true,
    edittype:'checkbox',
    editoptions:{value:"true:false"}
},
{
    name:"vits.value",
    label:'VITS',
    width:300,
    align:'center',
    editable:true,
    jsonmap:"aptitudeArrayList.0.value"
},
{
    name:"vits.color",
    editable:true,
    jsonmap:"aptitudeArrayList.0.color"
}
...
```

Here are the Edit options: *(I commented out postdata as its not needed as of now)*

```
var editOptions = {
    onclickSubmit:function (params, postdata) {
        params.url = URL + '/'; //+ postdata.id;
    }
};
```

After the edit is called, the data is sent to this function:

```
$.extend($.jgrid.edit, {
    closeAfterEdit:true,
    closeAfterAdd:true,
    ajaxEditOptions:{ contentType:"application/json" },
    mtype:'PUT',
    serializeEditData:function (data) {
        delete data.oper;
        return JSON.stringify(data);
    }
});
```

The inadequate code above returns this JSON:

```
{
  "id":"1",
  "name":"Barop",
  "region":"The end",
  "line":"FIRST_LINE",
  "cell":"12412",
  "available":"true",
  "vits.value":"2",
  "vits.color":"RED"
  ...
}
```

When I attach the debugger I find that `data` contains: `dataObject { id="1", name="Barop",  region="The end", ... vits.value="2", vits.color="RED"}` It seems it is getting the keys from the `name` attribute in jqGrid.

How would I go about serializing my data to a format that the server requires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way to solve your problem seems to me the modification of the `serializeEditData` which you use. It can be about the following

```
serializeEditData: function (data) {
    return JSON.stringify({
        id: parseInt(data.id, 10),
        name: data.name,
        line: data.line,
        cell: parseInt(data.cell, 10),
        available: data.available === 'true',
        aptitudeArrayList: [
            value: data.value,
            color: data.color
        ]
    });
}
```

Moreover I recommend you better not use points or any other [meta-characters](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) in the `name` property. Either you can just rename `name: "vits.value"` to `name: "value"` or use additional `index` property

```
name: "value",
index: "vits.value",
jsonmap: "aptitudeArrayList.0.value"
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, thank you! Reading through your answers on other questions has greatly helped me as well.

Comment: @Jaym: You are welcome! I'm glad to read that my other answers could help you too.